# How to get RequireConfirmedAccount in Razor page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

How to retrieve the SignInOptions.RequireConfirmedAccount value(false in my case) which I set in the identity service injection?

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Comment: Could you please tell me where you want to retrieve SignInOptions.RequireConfirmedAccount value inside the program.cs or else?

Comment: I want to get the value in the OnPost() of page model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer finally.

```
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

    public MyModel(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
```

Then in anywhere on the page, use

```
_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount
```